# hive or impala function to get substring of a string

Tags: hive, impala

My string(its a hive query) is having many FROM and JOIN statements and i want to use Regex function to get all the sub-strings after these statements.

Below is the sample string:
str=
'select col1, col2, col3 from dbname.table1,table2
left JOIN table3
on id=id
cross JOIN table4
where filter='check'
AND row<1
AND id=5'

Required output should be:

Ex:
select Regex(str,'from ') => dbname.table1,table2

select Regex(str,'JOIN ') => table3 table4

Comment: I'm afraid that your question is not clear enough to provide an answer. Specially what you have tried to explain with x,y,z. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I hope it is clear now...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression to capture the tables followed by `FROM` or `JOIN` keyword.

```
((JOIN|join|From|from)\s)\w+((\.|,)\w+){0,}
```

Note that I have used keywords in simple and capital format. You can use only one format if the query string is consistent with the regex or you can do a case insensitive match.

The above regex will give the following result.

`Case 1` : From

Full Match: `from dbname.table1,table2`

Match Group1: `from`  (note the space at the end)

`Case 2` : Join

Full Match: `JOIN table3` and `JOIN table4`

Match Group1: `JOIN`  (note the space at the end)

On every match, now you can use `match group1` result to replace the unwanted prefix (`from`  or `JOIN` ) from the `full match` result to get the table names.

Use this site to play and learn regex: https://regex101.com/

**EDIT 1**

In hive

```sql
regexp_extract('fooblabar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 1)
```

will give you the first group. In this case, it's `bla`

**EDIT 2**

Small update on the regular expression to capture the result in group3

```
((JOIN|join|From|from)\s)(\w+((\.|,)\w+){0,})
```

This should do the trick

```
select split(trim(regexp_replace('select Id from test1 where join test2','((JOIN|join|From|from)\s)(\w+((\.|,)\w+){0,})',' $3')),' ');
```

Comment: I have tried but not working. Can you please help me on this. I am new to this function. Thanks

Comment: I have tried this but not giving any results:

Comment: select regexp_extract(“select Id from test1 where join test2”,’((JOIN|join|From|from)\s)\w+((\.|,)\w+){0,}’,1)